# How to revise the route format when transfer files from WIN to LINUX?

Tags: linux, windows, format

I used to use win2003 as my server,my web applicaion file has some files like `\image\forum\1.jpg`.
now, i plan to use CENTOS as my server. i notice that the route in linux is `/image/forum/1.jpg`.
question1: is the win route format is different with linux as i recognized?
question2: how to revise the route format before move to CENTOS? any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I build my code on a windows 2k3 machine and then roll out live to centos servers. It's always worked either way without changing a thing :-) It's never caused me an issue.

You should have no need to change your code